# Use row data from a database to find rows in dataframes that match and use data to generate a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame (`database_df`) that contains the general record with the IDs that are the same team in each of the lines, containing these values I need to find in two APIs (`api_1_df`, `api_2_df`) that I collect the data if there is a way to find the same home team and the away team on the same line in both APIs.

When found on the same lines, I need to generate a dataframe with the lines in common with the columns that demonstrate the game's identification code (`match_id`):

```py
import pandas as pd

api_1_id = "pressure_id"
api_2_id = "betfair_id"
api_1_match_id = "pressure_match_id"
api_2_match_id = "betfair_match_id"

database_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pressure_id': [101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203],
    'pressure_name': ["Rangers", "City", "Barcelona FC", "Real Madrid FC", "Liverpool", "Chelsea FC"],
    'betfair_id': [1001, 1002, 1003, 2001, 2002, 2003],
    'betfair_name': ["Rangers FC", "Manchester City", "Barcelona FC", "Real Madrid", "Liverpool FC", "Chelsea"]
})

api_1_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'match_id': [1, 3],
    'home_id': [101, 103],
    'home_name': ["Rangers", "Barcelona FC"],
    'away_id': [201, 203],
    'away_name': ["Real Madrid FC", "Chelsea FC"]
})

api_2_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'match_id': [123, 456, 789],
    'home_id': [1001, 1002, 1003],
    'home_name': ["Rangers", "City", "Barcelona FC"],
    'away_id': [2001, 2002, 2003],
    'away_name': ["Real Madrid", "Liverpool FC", "Chelsea"]
})

def api_1_and_api_2_ids(api_1_df: pd.DataFrame, database_df: pd.DataFrame, api_2_df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    result = []
    for _, row in api_1_df.iterrows():
        home_id: pd.DataFrame = database_df.loc[database_df[api_1_id] == row['home_id']]
        away_id: pd.DataFrame = database_df.loc[database_df[api_1_id] == row['away_id']]

        home_id = home_id[api_2_id].iloc[0]
        away_id = away_id[api_2_id].iloc[0]

        matched_rows: pd.DataFrame = api_2_df[(api_2_df['home_id'] == home_id) & (api_2_df['away_id'] == away_id)]
        if not matched_rows.empty:
            result.append({api_1_match_id: row['match_id'], api_2_match_id: matched_rows.iloc[0]['match_id']})
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[api_1_match_id, api_2_match_id])
    result_df = result_df.sort_values(by=[api_1_match_id])
    print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
pressure_match_id  betfair_match_id
                1               123
                3               789
```

I would like to improve this method that I am using because it is slow in a large dataframe and I would also like indications of visual improvement because I am finding it very messy and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop and iterative concatenation need to go away. This is just a series of merges. You might be able to add some micro-optimizations to make the merges more efficient (making indices, changing the merge order, etc.), but the broad strokes can look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

api_1_id = "pressure_id"
api_2_id = "betfair_id"
api_1_match_id = "pressure_match_id"
api_2_match_id = "betfair_match_id"


def api_1_and_api_2_ids(
    api_1_df: pd.DataFrame,
    database_df: pd.DataFrame,
    api_2_df: pd.DataFrame,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    db_to_1_home = pd.merge(left=api_1_df, right=database_df, left_on='home_id', right_on=api_1_id)
    db_to_1_away = pd.merge(left=api_1_df, right=database_df, left_on='away_id', right_on=api_1_id)

    db_1_2_home = pd.merge(left=db_to_1_home, right=api_2_df, left_on=api_2_id, right_on='home_id',
                           suffixes=['_api1', '_api2'])
    db_1_2 = pd.merge(left=db_to_1_away, right=db_1_2_home, left_on=api_2_id, right_on='away_id_api2',
                      suffixes=['_away', '_home'])
    result_df = db_1_2[['match_id_api1', 'match_id_api2']].rename(columns={
        'match_id_api1': api_1_match_id,
        'match_id_api2': api_2_match_id,
    })

    return result_df


def test() -> None:
    database_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'pressure_id': [101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203],
        'pressure_name': ["Rangers", "City", "Barcelona FC", "Real Madrid FC", "Liverpool",
                          "Chelsea FC"],
        'betfair_id': [1001, 1002, 1003, 2001, 2002, 2003],
        'betfair_name': ["Rangers FC", "Manchester City", "Barcelona FC", "Real Madrid",
                         "Liverpool FC", "Chelsea"]
    })

    api_1_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'match_id': [1, 3],
        'home_id': [101, 103],
        'home_name': ["Rangers", "Barcelona FC"],
        'away_id': [201, 203],
        'away_name': ["Real Madrid FC", "Chelsea FC"]
    })

    api_2_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'match_id': [123, 456, 789],
        'home_id': [1001, 1002, 1003],
        'home_name': ["Rangers", "City", "Barcelona FC"],
        'away_id': [2001, 2002, 2003],
        'away_name': ["Real Madrid", "Liverpool FC", "Chelsea"]
    })

    result_df = api_1_and_api_2_ids(api_1_df, database_df, api_2_df)

    print(result_df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

```
   pressure_match_id  betfair_match_id
0                  1               123
1                  3               789
```